# Find the creator of a particular Unix socket

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, socket

I'm struggling to find out which process exactly created a Unix socket.

I've read couple posts about it like using `lsof -nl` (which generally gets the pid of a process which listens to Unix socket), using `netstat -tulpen` which doesn't show the socket I'm searching for and etc.

Basically what I want is that `gnome-keyring` process listens to some unix socket (`/run/user/1000/keyring-.../ssh`) but which process exactly created that socket? Is there any command that would help me to find which process exactly (I could use Unix socket name if that would be helpful) created a socket? thanks.

**P.S**
Should not that information be held somewhere in `/proc/pid/...`?

Comment: you could use `auditd` or `SystemTap` or `sysdig` but these would have to be in advance up and logging what you're interested in, and will not help if the creation has already happened

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot know it.

A simple `lsof /run/user/1000/keyring-.../ssh` will print the list of the processes that have the file (or the pipe) open in that moment.

If a process created a file and, therefore, ended, any information on it is lost.